# Adding spaces after each character in a string

Tags: string, bash, sed, scripting, formatting

I have a string variable in my script, made up of the 9 permission characters from ls -l

eg:

> rwxr-xr--

I want to manipulate it so that it displays like this:

```
r w x     r - x     r - -
```

IE every three characters is tab separated and all others are separated by a space. The closest I've come is using a printf

```
printf "%c %c %c\t%c %c %c\t%c %c %c\t/\n" "$output"{1..9}
```

This only prints the first character but formatted correctly

I'm sure there's a way to do it using "sed" that I can't think of

Any advice?

Comment: Any advice? [Don't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The output from [stat(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) is much easier to handle programmatically.

Comment: `echo "$output"{1..9}` will show you where your command is going wrong . . .

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks very much for your suggestion! This, however, is for an assignment and we were told to ignore weird situations like what you describe. 

However, you are absolutely correct that in general, I should keep that in mind. Unfortunately, I am way too far in having used ls -l to rewrite.... my question is solely with regards to simply formatting a string of 9 characters in the way I ask

Comment: @ruakh: I know why it doesn't work... because each time it reprocesses the variable. Hence why I said it's the closest I've come but I may need to use a "sed" command instead.

Comment: Hint: use a regular expression match to populate `BASH_REMATCH` with one character per array element.

Comment: @triplee ...with the caveat that `stat`'s output format isn't defined by POSIX, and so can vary by platform. If you're only targeting systems with the GNU variant, though, agreed that it's the Right Way to solved this problem.

Comment: I should clarify: I actually need everything that ls -l outputs, only I need to display them in a different manner. That's the assignment. I've managed to do quite a bit but this was leaving me blank. 

John Kugelman's answer below is exactly what I was looking for. I know I thought of that but am at a loss as to how I didn't try it. It bothers me I didn't know that

Answer (score 7):

Using the Posix-specified utilities `fold` and `paste`, split the string into individual characters, and then interleave a series of delimiters:

```
fold -w1 <<<"$str" | paste -sd'  \t'
```

Comment: Not sure but doesn't POSIX paste require a STDIN to be stated with -?

Comment: @jaypal Yes, but with -s it's not usually needed.

Comment: a.k.a. "how to print Continuous Integration pipeline secret because secret with spaces between characters will not be replaced by asterisks"

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.)(.)(.)/\1 \2 \3\t/g' <<< "$output"
r w x   r - x   r - -
```

Sadly, this leaves a trailing tab in the output. If you don't want that, use:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.)(.)(.)/\1 \2 \3\t/g; s/\t$//' <<< "$str"
r w x   r - x   r - -
```

Comment: Why does this remind me of a scene from *Total Recall*?

Comment: @John Kugelman - Trying this now but it looks exactly like what I was going for! And I do want a trailing \t

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Why do u need to parse them? U can access to every element of string by copy needed element. It's a very easy and without any utility, for example:

```
DATA="rwxr-xr--"

while [ $i -lt ${#DATA} ]; do
 echo ${DATA:$i:1}
 i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "rwxr-xr--" | awk '{gsub(/./,"& ");gsub(/. . . /,"&\t")}1'
r w x   r - x   r - -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "rwxr-xr--" | sed 's/\(.\{3,3\}\)/\1\t/g;s/\([^\t]\)/\1 /g;s/\s*$//g'
r w x    r - x    r - -
```

( Evidently I didn't put much thought into my `sed` command. John Kugelman's version is obviously much clearer and more concise. )

**Edit:** I wholeheartedly agree with triplee's comment though. Don't waste your time trying to parse `ls` output. I did that for a *long* time before I figured out you can get exactly what you want (and *only* what you want) **much** easier by using `stat`. For example:

```
> stat -c %a foo.bar  # Equivalent to stat --format %a
0754
```

The `-c %a` tells `stat` to output the access rights of the specified file, in octal. And that's *all* it prints out, thus eliminating the need to do wacky stuff like `ls foo.bar | awk '{print $1}'`, etc.

So for instance you could do stuff like:

```
GROUP_READ_PERMS=040
perms=$(stat -c %a foo.bar)
if (( (perms & GROUP_READ_PERMS) != 0 )); then
  ... # Do some stuff
fi
```

Sure as heck beats parsing strings like "rwxr-xr--"

Answer (score 0):

Setting `awk -F ''` allows each character to be bounded, then you'll want to loop through and print each field.

Example:

```
ls -l | sed -n 2p | awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf " %s ",$i;}}'; echo ""
```

The part seems like the answer to your question:

```
awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf " %s ",$i;}}'
```

I realize, this doesn't provide the trinary grouping you wanted though. hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.../& /2g;s/./& /g' YourFile
```

in 2 simple step

Answer (score 0):

A version which includes a pure `bash` version for short strings, and `sed` for longer strings, and preserves newlines (adding a space after them too)

```
if [ "${OS-}" = "Windows_NT" ]; then
  threshold=1000
else
  threshold=100
fi

function escape()
{
  local out=''
  local -i i=0
  local str="${1}"
  if [ "${#str}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
    # Faster after sed is started
    sed '# Read all lines into one buffer
         :combine
         $bdone
         N
         bcombine
         :done
         s/./& /g' <<< "${str}"
  else
    # Slower, but no process to load, so faster for short strings. On windows
    # this can be a big deal
    while (( i < ${#str} )); do
      out+="${str:$i:1} "
      i+=1
    done
    echo "$out"
  fi
}
```

Explanation of sed. "If this is the last line, jump to `:done`, else append Next into buffer and jump to `:combine`. After `:done` is a simple sed replacement expression. The entire string (newlines and all) are in one buffer so that the replace works on newlines too (which are lost in some of the `awk -F` examples)

*Plus* this is Linux, Mac, and Git for Windows compatible.